# manim camera.move_to and camera.scale at the same time don't work

Tags: python, animation, manim

Here is a sample code:

```
from manim import *
import numpy as np


class Problem(MovingCameraScene):
    def construct(self):
        circle_left = Circle(radius=2).move_to(np.array([-3, 0, 0]))
        circle_right = Circle(radius=2).move_to(np.array([3, 0, 0]))
        self.add(circle_left, circle_right)
        self.wait()
        self.play(self.camera.frame.animate.move_to(circle_left.get_center()), self.camera.frame.animate.scale(2))
        self.wait()
```

What I don't understand is why it just zooms out and doesn't moves to the left and zooms out at the same time, only to end up centered around `circle_left` AND zoomed out. It looks like `self.camera.frame.animate.move_to(circle_left.get_center())` was ignored.

I know that separating them in two `self.play` works but I would like both the zooming out and the moving to the left circle happening at the same time :/

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Manim doesn't handle simultaneous animations called on the same mobject in that manner. Instead, you can actually chain animations with the `.animate` syntax to get the effect you want. So:

```py
self.camera.frame.animate.move_to(<code>).scale(<code>)
```

Refer to the tutorial in the docs for more context:

https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/tutorials/building_blocks.html#animating-methods